# Page is reloaded on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-events

I have got a web page with a lot of components. There are a lot of buttons and when I click on them they don`t reload a page but when I click on buttons that are inside this code:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:250px; float:left; position:absolute; z-index:4">
    <form style="width:100%;">
        <fieldset style="width:250px; height:210px;">
        <legend><b>Authors</b></legend>
        <div id="authors" style="width:250px; height:150px; position:absolute; overflow:scroll">
            <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                <button class="button removeclick" style="display:block; float:left;"><img src="img/list-remove.png" alt="remove" /></button>
                <button class="button upclick" style="display:block; float:left;"><img src="img/arrow-up.png" alt="arrow-up" /></button>
                <button class="button downclick" style="display:block; float:left;"><img src="img/arrow-down.png" alt="arrow-down" /></button> 
                <input  class="resizable" type="text" style="height:29px"/>
            </div>
            <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                <button class="button removeclick" style="display:block; float:left;"><img src="img/list-remove.png" alt="remove" /></button>
                <button class="button upclick" style="display:block; float:left;"><img src="img/arrow-up.png" alt="arrow-up" /></button>
                <button class="button downclick" style="display:block; float:left;"><img src="img/arrow-down.png" alt="arrow-down" /></button> 
                <input  class="resizable" type="text" style="height:29px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="position:absolute; top:180px;"><button id="add" class="button" style="display:block; float:right;"><img src="img/add_new.png" alt="add new" /> Add New</button></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
```

The page is reloaded and I do not know why. I don't need this behaviour.

Comment: Have you checked the javascript ? 

May be handlers are attached with these buttons.

Comment: Can I see the other components? It's too confusing with just this and your styling, maybe some buttons just overlaps the other. Or try `<input type = "button"/>` instead of `<button></button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the opening form tag to be:

```
<form style="width:100%;" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: thanks. it works great. And when I click on buttons inside form they do their stuff correctly. I also need to validate fields in this form. I`ll try form validation plugin. If it works it will be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

that is because they are inside a `form`, if you dont need to submit there is no point of having a form,  remove

```
<form style="width:100%;">
```

and

```
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the form attribute from the code, the input fields inside the form attribute submits the form on Enter press..

Answer (score 1):

Delete the tag `form` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

All buttons have to be located inside the **Form** tag.

Clicking an a button located inside the **Form** tag submits and posts the form to the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

try `preventDefault();` in your javascript if you don't want the page to reload:

in jQuery like this:

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: He didn't post the javascript but tagged the question with jQuery and javascript. So I assume he uses javascript and posted an example how to prevent the form to submit.